# PHP pChart x-axis Label Angle

Tags: php, pchart

Does anyone know how to change the angle of the x-axis labels in pChart? I need to slant them so a longer timeframe can be displayed in a single graph.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For pChart 2, it can be configured with the 'LabelRotation' format option of the drawScale method:

```
$image->drawScale( array( ... , 'LabelRotation'=>10  , ... ) );
```

Have look at the documentation of the drawScale:
http://wiki.pchart.net/doc.doc.draw.scale.html

Comment: Can you get it to rotate the text too? If I put label rotation to 90 this just writes the label downwards, it doesn't actually rotate it. No good for numbers.